# SQL subquery in Hibernate Query Language

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am new to HQL and I am working on subqueries.

I have the following SQL subquery:

```
select * from (
    select * from table order by columnname
) as subquery 
where columnvalue = 'somevalue';
```

I want to fire the query in HQL. I wrote the below code :

```
Result = session.createQuery("from (from table order by columnname) as subquery where columnvalue = :somevalue")
    .setParameter(/*setting all parameters*/)
    .list();
```

I am getting this exception:

> QuerySyntaxException : unexpedted token :( line 1, column 10 [from (from ...)]

My SQL query is giving me correct results. **How do I write it in HQL ?**

Comment: can you write the the real query that you are using?

Comment: select * from (select * from employee order by salary) as subquery where  manager = 'XYZ' order by department;

Comment: Why do you have a subquery? Either you want to sort by salary, or you want to sort by department !?!?!?

Comment: Sorry typo : select * from (select * from employee order by salary) as subquery where manager = 'XYZ' group by department. I want to sort by salary (in descending order) and find the employee with highest salary in each department, hence group by department. I need to write the query in hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I did not think HQL could do subqueries in the from clause

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries

note the sentence:

`Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.`

It will be better if you excute `native SQL`.

Comment: I am trying to executing the query as native SQL, but it is throwing "org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet" exception. I am firing is as below : session.createSQLQuery("select * from (select * from employee order by salary) as subquery where manager = 'XYZ' group by department").